# version control & code hosting - im lost

Tags: svn, version-control

i'm working on a small project that might have an additional coder at some point - i've become to used to svn (which i started using very recently, through sourceforge) and want to use it for this project, without having to publish the code on the internet -- which would happen if i were to add it a sourceforge project.

I have some hosting space (dreamhost) with shell access, and ideally i'd like a web-fronted version control s/w that i can install on my dreamhost account, and tinker away at my project wherever i happen to be.

there appear to be a number of possibilities (reviewboard.org, trac etc) that seem like they *might* work - but is there a simple barebones system somewhere that i can just quickly install without too much hacking?

thanks!

Comment: dreamhost supports SVN out of the box you don't need anything else, that said, I am using GIT against a dreamhost account with much success

Comment: got it running on dreamhost - they also pointed me to tortoiseSVN (even though i was happy enough with netbeans) and it seems to be working very well indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dreamhost has native support for creating svn/trac instances right within their panel.

It's under Goodies -> Subversion.  Lets you choose the subdomain you want it installed on, set users and passwords and whether its hidden or publicly visible by default.  There's a checkbox for installing Trac, though you'll have to go back in and lock that down if you don't want your project publicly viewable, which should only take a few minutes to do on Google.

I use this setup for all of my projects and its quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

I've used ProjectLocker.com for free Subversion hosting (for a student project).  It also hosts Trac as well.  I was pretty happy with the results, so just throwing it out there as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are a few. There's also plenty of svn hosting services, some even free. Check out [Bitnami Trac](http://bitnami.org/stack/trac) if you're looking to set up your own. It's just a stack that has svn/trac/ etc. all installed and ready to go.

Otherwise if you'd go with hosted services, some are free: ["google: 10 Free SVN & Project Hosting Services"](http://www.straw-dogs.co.uk/09/20/6-free-svn-project-hosting-services/)

Comment: The link above is to a page that is solidly out of date (some of the entries are no longer free, etc.).  Just search for Free SVN Hosting and you'll get a current list.

Answer (score 0):

Running SVN server is easy - you just run `svnserve`. SVN can also access repository through SSH, in that case no SVN server is needed.

If you want web frontend too, I recommend Trac - we are using it in the company I work for, and many open-source projects are using it too (even if they do not use SVN). Trac installation is pretty easy (via `easy_install`) and contains stand-alone webserver (but can also be served via FastCGI, CGI...). See [documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall). If you use SQLite as a database, you don't even need to setup MySQL or PostgreSQL.

DreamHost looks good, Python seems to be officialy supported (Trac is implemented in Python), so there should be no big problems (or no problems at all).

Answer (score 0):

[Assembla](http://assembla.com) has always treated me well. It has SVN, Trac, plus a heap of other stuff. It's not free for private hosting, but it's darned cheap. You could always just make a public project to test out the tools first to see if you like it.